# dDjango Tempalte TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I want to add CSS and Js file path into header and footer for load CSS and js files for web template but I'm getting this error.

I load {% load static  %}

**TemplateSyntaxError at /**
***Could not parse the remainder:*** 
'/css/bootstrap.min.css' from 'front/css/bootstrap.min.css'
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static front/css/bootstrap.min.css %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static front/css/font-awesome.css %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static front/js/plugins/swiper/swiper.css %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static front/js/plugins/magnific/magnific-popup.css %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static front/css/style.css %}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'front/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

note: if you use double quotes outside brackets use single quote inside

Answer (score 0):

## change this into

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static front/css/bootstrap.min.css %}">`

## this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'front/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

add a single quotas after the static.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!  However I found this nearly identical to the existing, accepted answer so I'm recommending it for deletion to keep answers focused.  Cheers,